# How to style an html link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Really simple question;

I have a link in HTML that I need to resize, I have edited the CSS file to create this class:

```
.redirect {
font-size: 1em;
}
```

In the main PHP file I have the tag set up as follows ---->

```
<a class="redirect" href="https://www.irijobs.com"><font color="blue"><<       Click here to go back to irijobs.com homepage <<</font></a>
```

There has been absolutely no change in size... any pointers? I'm sure it's a simple syntax error.

Edit: Most of my styling errors were from the prior developer wrapping CSS in HMTL tags, which was not only unnecessary but confused the browser.

Comment: what's the relation to php?

Comment: you also missed to add the href to the class. HTML 101.

Comment: Lose the font tag (its obsolete) and just add `color: blue` to the class CSS, avoid `<` and `>` characters that are not part of a tag and use the entity escapes instead: https://jsfiddle.net/8grtdztz/

Comment: I removed the "php" tag; there was no relevance/code posted, only HTML. Please don't spam tag, it makes the question unclear also.

Comment: Fred, I am literally hopping back to html after years of not using it; so I will be making "101" errors. Also, sorry its a php file even though it was an html question, will note on that. Finally I am editing code I did not make myself so some errors are not mine.

Answer (score 3):

Font size 1em is equal to the current font size. You have to increase the em to see the changes, for example 1.5em or 2em to double the size.

```
.redirect {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `<font>` tag as it is deprecated since HTML 4. Just do the following and apply any size to `font-size`:

```css
.redirect {
  font-size:1em;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="redirect" href="https://www.irijobs.com"><<       Click here to go back to irijobs.com homepage << </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change `<` in `<<       Click here to go back to irijobs.com homepage <<` to `&lt;`. It is because browser thinks that `<` sign starts a new tag, like `<a>`.

Second, `font-size: 1em` means that font size is equal to default. `2em` is 2 times bigger, and `0.5em` is half of original size.

I suggest you to change `<font>` tag to CSS rule `color:blue;`. `<font>` tag is deprecated in favor of CSS `color` property.

Also, multiple spaces are displayed as single one.

CSS:

```
.redirect {
  font-size: 2em; /* or some another value, may be also in pixels (like 20px) or points (like 16pt)*/
  color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="redirect" href="https://www.irijobs.com">&lt;&lt; Click here to go back to irijobs.com homepage &lt;&lt;</a>
```

Comment: Okay, so I have made these edits; there are still no changes and now the link is purple. I am sure that the css file is attached (as the application form would not display otherwise).

Comment: Are you sure that the CSS file is not from browser cache? I have opened this code in chrome and it works properly

Comment: Marcin; you were right. What's weirder is I'm now trying to follow the guide on stack to eliminate this issue through dev options and it just won't wipe that damn cache. It's a work computer though; mine works fine. Thanks though; you were the only one to actually figure out the actual problem.